# Laravel 8 authorizeResources in the controller constructor doesn't work for edit action

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

I wrote a policy for a Post model in laravel 8.

When I use

```
public function __construct()
    {
       $this->authorizeResource(Post::class, 'post');
    }
```

in the controller, the policy is correctly applied for index, create actions but not for edit action.

If I delete the  line in the constructor and modify the edit action like this

```
 public function edit( $id)
    {   
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $this->authorize('update', $post);
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $author = User::find($post->author_id);
        return view('posts.edit', compact('post', 'author'));
       
    }
```

> only the line   $this->authorize('update', $post); is added

then it works properly.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong

Hereafter are the controller and the policy

**Controller (not completed)**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;use App\Models\User
;use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create the controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
       //$this->authorizeResource(Post::class, 'post');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    { 
        //authorization managed by the constructor
        $user = auth()->user();
    //$this->authorize('viewAny', Post::class);
       
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(25);
        return view('posts.index', compact('posts', 'user'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
       // $this->authorize('create', Post::class);
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
       //authorization is managed globally in the constructor
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'abstract' => 'required',
            'body' => 'required'
        ]);
        $post = new Post;
        $post->title = $request->input('title');
        $post->abstract = $request->input('abstract');
        $post->body = $request->input('body');
        $post->author_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $post->category = $request->input('category');
        $post->beg_date = $request->input('beg_date');
        $post->end_date = $request->input('end_date');
        $post->close_date = $request->input('close_date');
        $post->sticky = $request->input('sticky');
        $post->diaporama_dir = $request->input('diaporama_dir');
        $post->receive_registration = $request->input('receive_registration');
        $post->inscription_directive = $request->input('inscription_directive');
        $post->save();
        return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'Article enregistré !');
    

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Post $post)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit( $id)
    {   
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $this->authorize('update', $post);
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $author = User::find($post->author_id);
        return view('posts.edit', compact('post', 'author'));
       
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Post $post)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**Policy**

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class PostPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;


    /**
 * Perform pre-authorization checks.
 *
 * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
 * @param  string  $ability
 * @return void|bool
 */
    public function before(User $user, $ability)
    {
     if ($user->role=='admin') {
        return Response::allow();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any models.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return ($user->role==='admin' || $user->role==='writer' || $user->role==='manager')
            ? Response::allow()
            : Response::deny(__("You are not allowed to view any posts!"));
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
     * @return mixed"
     */
    public function view(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        
        return $user->id == $post->user_id
                ? Response::allow()
                : Response::deny(trans("You cannot view this post because you are not its owner!"));
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create models.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return $user->role === 'writer' || $user->role ==='manager'
                ? Response::allow()
                : Response::deny(__("You are not allowed to create posts."));
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(User $user, Post $post)
    {
       

        return ($user->id == $post->user_id)
                ? Response::allow()
                : Response::deny(__("You cannot update this post because you are not its owner."));
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return $user->id == $post->user_id
                ? Response::allow()
                : Response::deny(__("You cannot update this post because you are not its owner."));
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can restore the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function restore(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return Response::deny();
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can permanently delete the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Post  $post
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function forceDelete(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For resource policy you need to use model binding in controller action:

```
public function edit(Post $post)
{   
    $author = User::find($post->author_id);
    return view('posts.edit', compact('post', 'author'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you may have noticed, only those bindings that require a parameter do not work.
The solution, which can only be reached by "poking", because nowhere is it specified that the arguments in the policy and controller must have the same name and type.

Example Policy:

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function view(User $user, User $model)
    {
        dd("It`s worked");
        return true;
    }

    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function update(User $user, User $model)
    {
        dd("It`s worked");
        return true;
    }

    public function delete(User $user, User $model)
    {
        dd("It`s worked");
        return true;
    }

    public function restore(User $user, User $model)
    {
        dd("It`s worked");
        return true;
    }

    public function forceDelete(User $user, User $model)
    {
        dd("It`s worked");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Example Controller

```
    class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(UserRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->authorizeResource($this->repository->getModelClass(), "user");
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // do something
    }

    public function create(): Response
    {
        // do something
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // do something
    }

    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        // do something
    }

    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        // do something
    }

    public function destroy(User $user)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use public function edit(Post $post) in place of edit($id) in the controller file.
salutations